# How to use ValueRenderOption in google-api-python-client for google sheets

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-sheets-api

Here is a code snippet:

```
import ast
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient import discovery

SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
CREDJSON = "some-cred-file-downloaded-from-dev-console.json"

def google_credentials(jsoncred=CREDJSON, scope=SCOPE):
    return ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(jsoncred, scope)


def csv_arrays(creds, key):

    (SHEETS, sheets) = sheets_fetch(creds, key)

    wks = sheets
    def create_filename(arg):
        filename = key.prefix + "_" + arg.get("properties, {}).get("title","Sheet1")
        filename = filename.replace(" ", "_")
        print (filename)
        return filename
    return [(create_filename(ws), ast.literal_eval(repr(SHEETS.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=key.key, range=(ws.get("properties", {}).get("title", "Sheet1"))).execute().get('values',[])))) for ws in wks] #.decode("utf-8")

def sheets_fetch(creds, key):
    print('Now doing:', key)
    SHEETS = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    sheet_metadata = SHEETS.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=key.key).execute()
sheets = sheet_metadata.get('sheets', '')

    return (SHEETS, sheets)
```

I have no problems getting the content of the cells. My problem is that they come formatted (as this is the default value) and I want them UNFORMATTED?

**How do I set the option in the query of the return statement from the csv_array function?**

https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption

As a side note, is there a way to get the cells value in other way than as a string ast-ed to a list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set a valueRenderOption of UNFORMATTED_VALUE with the python client, use:

`SHEETS.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=key.key, range=myRange, valueRenderOption='UNFORMATTED_VALUE').execute()`

Additionally, when using UNFORMATTED_VALUE, the response will be typed as it is in Sheets (e.g, numbers will be numbers, bools will be bools, strings will be strings).  Dates are either strings or numbers, depending on [DateTimeRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/DateTimeRenderOption), see the [Date/Time Serial Numbers Guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts#datetime_serial_numbers) for more information on dealing with the dates as numbers.

Because the values are already typed properly, you shouldn't need to do any additional parsing with ast or repr.

Comment: The first version works. I need to remove both the repr and ast to make "get the data typed as its actual type, instead of always as a string" can you update you answer so I can accept it?